# RegExp VBS 5.5, is it possible to escape long characters sequence? (\Q...\E)

Tags: regex, vbscript

Is it possible to do something like this in Microsoft VBS 5.5 regexp:

```
\QLong.String?!With.Random,Ch\aract\er\s.\E
```

so it will find "Long.String?!With.Random,Ch\aract\er\s." without converting dot to "any character" etc.? This regexp works fine in Notepad++ but doesn't work in VBS.

Comment: Please only use the tags  that are appropriate for your question. I removed the 'delphi' and 'c++builder' tags, as they have absolutely nothing to do with the question you're asking here. Tags are meant to help in organizing posts for searching, and group them so that people who are interested in those topics can spot them. Adding tags that are not applicable to the post defeats both of those goals. Thanks.

Comment: I added them because I thought many C++ Builder and Delphi programmers use VBS regexps.

Comment: Please don't do that. :-) If your question  is about VBS, use the VBS tag. If your question is on a car site, and you're asking questions about your 'Yugo', people tend to get angry if you add the 'Porsche' and 'Lamborghini' tags to it. :-)

Comment: Your assumption may be right though, since all these products (VBS, C++ Builder, to some extent Delphi) are long dead and nobody really uses them any more. What the hell are you doing with VBS anyway?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I was forced to use C++ Builder 6.0 for one of my projects :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, this isn't possible. According to the [Regular Expression Syntax (Scripting) documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), the `\Q..\E` metacharacter escape sequence isn't supported.

There really isn't a substitute I can see in VBScript, short of inserting escapes before the reserved characters before running a rexex.